# Can I use N.E.I. every time i play?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

Is it possible to always have Not Enough Items set up every time I play Minecraft even without Forge? Can I for example open Minecraft and choose my normal profile not Forge, and when I play have Forge set up. If this isn't possible can I make another profile that uses N.E.I. only and leaves the other mods I have for the forge profile?

Comment: In an earlier version I did this with the Tekkit modpack, I imported it into my minecraft.jar file and was able to run it in vanilla Minecraft. I believe you should still be able to do the same style of thing, but I can't remember the specific steps just now.

Comment: As an extra note: forge in itself doesn't do anything, I assume you are talking about (multiple) mods that use forge as a modloader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Minecraft Forum Thread](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/909223-164-smp-chickenbones-mods/), Not Enough Items will not work without Forge. Which means you need to have Forge installed. If all you want is NEI, just make a separate profile containing only Forge and Not Enough Items.

Comment: the problem is i have about 23 mobs how do i make a profile thats only has NEI

Comment: Like I said, you need to make a new profile, and install only Forge and NEI into it. NEI will not work without Forge. Forge by itself does nothing anyway, so I don't see the problem. Could you explain a bit further?